# what do i have to do to make a imagebutton launch a other app in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm creating an app. but now i want it to open a other app with a imagebutton. i searched google for like 5 days there are many awnsers but not the right one.

there are awnsers but not the full explaination.

i found this part

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);`

but where do i have to put this so it works on my imagebutton. and what classes or things do i have to make.

This is my appactifity.java

```
    package eu.cornholio.rom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CornholioROMActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


}
```

and this is my main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:settings="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.settings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cornh" android:contentDescription="@string/cornholio"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cornholio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cwm" android:clickable="true" android:contentDescription="@string/cmw"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/jkay"
         android:clickable="true"
          android:contentDescription="@string/jkay"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

here my code

```
    package eu.cornholio.rom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class CornholioROMActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //finding your image button
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewByid(R.id.imageButton1);

        //setting onClick listener
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("eu.chainfire.cfroot.cwmmanager",
                                       "eu.chainfire.cfroot.cwmmanager.MainActivity"));
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });

    }

}
```

greetz drgekko

Comment: Yes exactly in onClicklistner of your ImageButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set onClickListener to your ImageButton.

```
yourImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address",
                               "com.package.address.MainActivity"));
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
```

---

**Update**

for example, if you want to set click action on `imageButton1`, then you need to do the following changes in your *onCreate* method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //finding your image button
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    //setting onClick listener
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address",
                                   "com.package.address.MainActivity"));
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: oke where do i have to putt this ? inside the xml where the button is?

Comment: inside your code; after finding your control and referencing to it

Comment: oke but in what file and where exaly my button is in main.xml and this is the button     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/jkay"
         android:clickable="true"
          android:contentDescription="@string/jkay" />

Comment: paste your Activity code in your question so i can help you appropriately

Comment: 1. ComponentName cannot be resolved to a type 2. Imagebutton cannot be resolved to a type 3. Imagebutton cannot be resolved to a type 4. OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type 5. The constructor Intent(string) is undifined 6. the method findViewByIf(int) is undefined for the type CornholioROMActifity 7 View cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: are you importing all the required classes? press **Ctrl+Shift+O** in eclipse while having activity code file opened

Comment: oops, it was a typo. Actual method is `findViewById`

Comment: hahaha edit it but it still gives the same error only with id :p now

Comment: paste your entire code file in question. I think you have selected android's **R** class in import reference

Comment: write it like this `ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);`. In your code you are writing **findViewByid**, but the actual method is **findViewById**. (Note **id** case)

Comment: oke that works but now is my problem how do i get imagebutton2 to open a other app :$

Comment: copy and paste the same block of code and replace some values like `ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);` and set listener as `btn2.setOnClickListener.......`

Comment: aighttt thnk you very much for youw help :P

Answer (score 0):

you have to define an OnClickListener for your ImageButton.

This would look somehow like this:

```
  myFancyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call another app without knowing the main activity:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address"); 
          startActivity(intent);

        }
});
```